# What is the benefit of distinguishing elements of a set instead of subsets of a set?

Tags: set-theory

What is the purpose of "is element of" relation instead of just using "is a subset of" relation for everything?

For example, instead of saying, "Set A has a subset B, and B contains an element c, so A contains the element a," why not model everything as subsets "all the way down." as in, "set A has subset B, and B has subset C, so A has subset C."

Comment: Because we usually deal with individuals like numbers that belong to set of numbers: intervals, functions.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks, so what is it about individuals that makes them better represented as elements instead of subsets? What do we lose by saying 1 is a subset of natural numbers?

Comment: How would you say that 3 is a prime number if you didn't have the member operator? Saying that {3} is a subset of the prime numbers does not work, because then you have to explain what the significance of {3} is, and without the membership operator, you can't say that 3 is the only member of {3}. There are ways around these difficulties, but why would anyone want to bother?

Comment: @DavidGudeman I don't understand. I'm asking the purpose of the notion of element in the first place, but you're asking how to represent a set {3} with the element 3 for "membership"? Why can't 3 be a subset of prime numbers that is "named" 3 to represent such membership?

Comment: @csp, are you asking why set theory has individuals? It's because that's how people think so it's convenient to do the formalization that way. It's probably possible to define a set theory without individuals. I believe Quine had a version of his nf set theory which did not have individuals, but it's possible that's the version that was found to be inconsistent.

Comment: @DavidGudeman Ah, thanks. So the notion of elements is used to define a "bottom," sort of speak, so there isn't an infinite "going down?"

Comment: In various types of set theories element alone cannot be used to define a "bottom", you need a famous axiom called [Axiom of regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity) in ZFC. And symmetrically, you have many important non-wellfounded axioms of various set theories without a bottom such as  Aczel's [AFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-well-founded_set_theory)...

Comment: The concepts of *element* and *subset* are both semantically and syntactically distinct. It would make no sense not to distinguish between the two.

Comment: What you propose is actually called [mereology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mereology) which was a rival foundation as opposed to set theory where your *subset* relation is called *parthood* relation...

Comment: FWIW it is possible to do set theory without elements. This is known as ETCS, the elementary theory of the category of sets. Sadly it does not appear to have a Wikipedia page. Here's one page on it, you can Google around for others. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCS. "The theory intends to capture in an invariant way the notion of a (constant) ‘abstract set’ whose elements lack internal structure and whose only external property is cardinality with further external relations arising from mappings."

Answer (score 1):

First order logic quantifies over elements. Second order logic can quantify over subsets of sets whilst third order logic can quantify over subsets of subsets of sets and so on. Higher order logic was a going concern in the early 20C until it was eventually eclipsed by set theory. As Quine emphasised we should see set theory as a higher order logic.

First order logic is called elementary. Often it has properties which aren't shared by higher logics. For example completeness. Everything that can be semantically proven can be done so syntactically and vice-versa. However, higher logics do not share this property of first order logic and so they are incomplete and so must set theory.

This displays an essential difference between quantifying over individuals as opposed to quantifying over sets of individuals. Another way of thinking about  this is again through logic. Properties are exemplified by sets of individuals. So by not allowing such sets, we are not allowing quantification over properties, aka propositions.

There is also possible to talk about ur-elements which are rather like atomic elements.

Answer (score 0):

Since the concept of subsets is defined from the concept of elements, it would be more reasonable to deny the former than the latter, and in set theories without the powerset axiom, this denial can be situated quite intelligibly: here, for example, we do not say that for any given set *A*, there is some other set *B* that has all of the subsets of *A*, but we might deny that there is a way to set together all such things from some infinite *A*.

More pointedly, then, if we went with only subsets, we'd end up saying something weird/absurd like, "A set is equal to the set of all its own subsets." So 4 would be equivalent to the set of all its subsets; but in von Neumann format, say, 4 = {0, 1, 2, 3}, and it is an easy argument by algebraic rote to show that the powerset of 4 as such has 16 elements; so this would be as much as to say that 4 = 16, and arbitrarily many other false equivalences would appear.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not mathematical, but conceptual.

Mathematically:

A *subset* is also a set (notice the suffix *(sub)set*), not only a *sub-[anything]* of a set. Mathematically, if you define something as an *element*, it is not necessary for it to be a *set* (e.g. a variable has no mathematical parts).

So, the answer is: There is no benefit: it is inconsistent to associate an element with a subset.

Conceptually:

Conceptually, it is almost the opposite; here's the answer:

*Because any element is always a set at the same time*, and what the observer does is simply applying the best approach.

According to the systems theory, a system (any object is a system (consider that object is anything that a subject interacts with (subject: you or me))) is a set of interrelated parts. Therefore, any part is also a system, and any system is also a part. For example: Rodriguez the dog (as a system) can be considered an element, or a part of a larger system (e.g. his big family of 15 dogs) or a system made of multiple parts (e.g. [parts of a dog](https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/diagram-showing-different-part-dog_1308-31269.jpg)).

Why is an element always a set? Because in our mind, all of our ideas are interrelated, they are not a hierarchy. A Dad can be a set of limbs. A limb can be a set of atoms. An atom can be a set of strings (yes, as in the strings theory). A string can be a set of smaller lines. A line is a set of two points. A point is a set of attributes of a space. An attribute is a set of qualities. A quality is a set of impressions. An impression is a set of intuitions. An intuition is a set of inputs. An input is a set of contents. A content...